# Play Video File with no extension

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to import a video file that has a name but no extension. I would like to play this video inside Unity's Video Player. How do I do this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.Video;

public class VideoHandler : MonoBehaviour
{

    string path;
    public VideoPlayer vp;

    void Start(){
     pathOfVid += @".mp4";
     vp.url = pathOfVid;
     vp.Play();
    }
}
```

The video file is named like this "Sample". The error I receive is:

```
WindowsMediaFoundation received empty file
```

and if I do not use ".mp4" in the path, I get this:

```
Can't play movie
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What type of video file is it?  Are you able to open it in any media player?

Comment: It is an mp4 and yes on my PC i can drag and drop to any media player and it works. I want to achieve the same with Unity's media player. What do you suggest how can I do this?

Comment: You may need to import the file after adding the extension.  Unity may need the extension to know how to handle the file.

Comment: So without any extension it won't work?

Comment: I was not able to find any conclusive information on this.  It does seem like the lack of file extension is causing a problem during the import process.  Other media programs may be looking for specific headers to determine format when file extension is missing.